How do we know it was Nemesis who killed Nicholai in RE3?
The fate of Nicholai Ginovaef / Nikolai Zinoviev depends on player choices. Here I'm talking about the specific outcome (Youtube link), where Jill encounters him at the Dead Factory, they have a short conversation during a shootout when suddenly we hear Nicholai's scream accompanied by some tentacle sounds. We see blood drips from above and the mercenary's body dragged up to the ceiling.
(I also should note that no Nemesis leitmotif "Feel the Tense" is played at this point; usually the near presence of Nemesis is indicated by this melody)
Everybody appears sure that it was Nemesis who kills Nicholai here. For example, the Fandom wiki says:

Nikolai will confront Jill about this true plans in Raccoon City, but will eventually be pulled through a hole in the roof by Nemesis and impaled by one his tentacles.

But how do we know this? It's not like Racoon City has a shortage of random mutant monsters. The only argument I can think of is that Jill encounters Nemesis in the next room (YouTube link). However,  the Treatment Room is supposed to be isolated from its environment for security reasons, so it seems unlikely to me that Nemesis is able to affect Nicholai from here. And if he could -- then surely he would attack Jill next, not waiting for her to enter the Treatment Room?
